# Java Reflection - Copy nested objects values

Tags: java, reflection, merge, nested, clone

I have an object, that might have other objects or list of objects. Is there a way to iterate through these objects to copy their values into a new object? What I want to do is merge 2 objects to update a document in my DB, so I don't want the null values.

So far I've reached the way to do a shallow copy with no nulls value for any object with this:

```
public Object merge(Object target) {
    try {
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f: fields) {
            if (f.get(this) != null) {
                f.set(target, f.get(this));
                System.out.println(f.get(this));
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        return target;
    }
    return target;
}
```

**Problem Statement:** But now, how can I handle nested objects? Like a `List` of `Car` objects for example?

Comment: Why are you doing it using reflection? Why are you doing it yourself instead of using an already existing library such as mapstruct? Collections such as lists or sets can be cloned but depending on your requirements and data cloning the elements themselves or any direct references (e.g. a single `Car` reference) could be hard.

Comment: i'm doing it using reflection because I don't want to be copying every field one by one since the only requirement is that it's not null. I knew about modelmapper which isnt working as I expected (I got it to do what I'm doing right now but it fails when I remove a value from a list, it doesn't remove it, for example) I'll check mapstruct

Comment: Well, merging collections isn't that easy. Assume you want to merge the lists `[A,B,C]` and `[D,B,C]` - what should the result be?

Comment: [A, B, C, D] (the order doesn't matter)

Comment: What doesn't quite fit "when I remove a value from a list, it doesn't remove it" - unless I'm not understanding it correctly. In my example the input lists could be the result of removing elements A or D yet you want to keep them in the merge result which would fit the behavior you described.

Comment: Imagine I have an object which has a string and a list of strings as fields. Well, what I need is that when I merge an object with it, if the String value isn't null, the target field will get updated. And same for the list. What happens now is that if I have [A, B, C] in the target object and the source object has [A, B], then the target object is getting [A, B, B] which I don't get at all why, it should be [A, B]

Comment: Well, any decent mapper should either replace the list entirely (thus if the source has [A,B] the target should look alike) or provide options to define how to merge the lists. If you "merge" [A,B] into [A,B,C] then getting a result of [A,B,B] is really strange.

Comment: If that was just a typo and you still get [A,B,C] after that "merge" then the settings or expectations might be wrong: if only nulls should be replaced and the target list isn't null then not replacing or changing it would match that requirement.

Comment: What it's doing is taking the second element of the updated object, aside of keeping the new one that was inserted. So if I update again with [A, M, C], it'll be that

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your requirements so could you edit your question and elaborate a little? Like what should happen if the source or target fields are null or if both aren't (please define that for single values and collections)? How should empty collections be treated? How should collection elements be treated - should they be cloned, should just the references be copied? Could collections contain null elements and if so how should those be handled? Please add examples to make your requirements easier to understand.